# Request for member 'pData' with BOOL value TRUE is not a structure or union-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I could not use the pData[4096] to pass it to the other function from main.

```
data.m
------
@implementation data
static int msgID;
static char pData[4096]="\0";

+ (void)initialize
{
 //some initialisations
msgID =123;
}

-(void)SwapEndian:(uint8_t*)pData withBOOLValue:(BOOL)bIsAlreadyLittleEndian
{
  NSLog("%s %s",pData,bIsAlreadyLittleEndian);
}
@end

main.m
-------

[dat SwapEndian:dat.pData withBOOLValue:TRUE];
```

I am getting pData undeclared. As pData is declared as static inside the Data

implementation i tried with dat.pData to pass it from main.But when i do it i am getting

Request for member 'pData' with BOOL value TRUE is not a structure or union.

Comment: You are not using Objective-C the way it is meant to be used. Sorry to be so blunt, but I think such things are important to know `:)`. Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @e.James:The pData buffer is filled with some values(like header,data and tailer) in a function called DataBuffer of class 'data'.Now i need to swap the whole buffer into Litte Indian format.So i have written a function inside the class for conversion.Now intially i'm just checking whether i'm getting the pData buffer with the values initialised by the DataBuffer function.So how do i need to pass the pData from the main.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to determine what the code is supposed to do, but here is how to create an Objective-C object that holds an integer identifier and a 4096-character array. Please note that this sort of thing is usually discouraged. Unless you have a really specific reason for using `int` and `char[]`, the identifier should be `NSInteger` and the data should be an `NSData` or `NSString` object.

I have also used some of the "standard" naming conventions. If you are writing Cocoa code, it helps to drink a *lot* of the Kool-Aid.

> **Message.h**:

```
@interface Message : NSObject
{
    int identifier;
    char data[4096];
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int indentifier;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) char * data;
- (void)swapEndian:(BOOL)flag;
@end
```

> **Message.m**:

```
@implementation Message

@synthesize identifier;
@synthesize data;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]) == nil) { return nil; }
    identifier = 0;
    data[0] = '\0';
    return self;
}

- (void)swapEndian:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"%s %d", data, flag);
}

@end
```

> **main.m**:

```
#import "Message.h"

...

Message * message = [[[Message alloc] init] autorelease];
message.identifier = 123;
[message swapEndian:YES];
```

Comment: error: type of property 'data' does not match type of ivar 'data' is coming in the @synthesize data declaration.I am having some value in the data buffer that is intialised in func1() and i need to pass it to the swapEndians function.How to pass this data buffer from main to the function swapEndian